# I want to create a checkbox function on Google Sheets using circles

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently, I can only copy paste shaded or unshaded circles. I want to make a function like the "Insert Checkbox" in Google Sheets. I would like to know if this is possible or if I should leave it to be manually done.

[image: Shaded circle picture]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot image about your goal from `I want to make a function like the "Insert Checkbox" function built into Google Sheets.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: How are these circles currently added to your sheet? Are they drawings? Do they belong to a specific cell? Could you provide a copy of the spreadsheet, in order to know these details?

Comment: And do you mean that you would like to insert blank circles in specific cells, and then be able to click on them to turn them into black circles, as the stages of a project are completed?  Or will you want them to change from blank to black based on values elsewhere in the spreadsheet?

Comment: @Kirkg13 - "And do you mean that you would like to insert blank circles in specific cells, and then be able to click on them to turn them into black circles, as the stages of a project are completed?" It's like you print('Words') out of my head! Yes, this is what I wanted to do.

Comment: @Iamblichus - They are currently special characters that are copy pasted into the sheet. They are not images.

Comment: @Tanaike - when I "copy" then "paste" the cell that has the function, I want it to appear as a "◯" then when I click it, I want it to become "⚫" and vice-versa

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about `I want it to appear as a "◯" then when I click it, I want it to become "⚫" and vice-versa`. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `when I "copy" then "paste" the cell that has the function`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

- You want to insert blank circles (◯) to specific cells (I guess the ones that are currently selected), via clicking a menu button, an inserted drawing or image, or what have you.
- You want to change the inserted blank circles to black circles (⚫) whenever these are clicked.

#### Solution:

Using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) (click `Tools > Script editor` to access it), you can do the following:

- Create a function that will fill all the active ranges with blank circles (let's call it `addBlankCircles`). Use [getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRangeList()) to get the selected ranges, and for each range, create a 2D array with the corresponding dimensions, filled with blank circles, and use [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) to add the blank circles to the range.
- Either create a [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms) (created by `onOpen` trigger) or [insert a clickable image or drawing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) to call the function `addBlankCircles`.
- Use an [onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) trigger to check whether the selected cell has the value ◯, and change it to ⚫ if that's the case.

#### Code snippet:

```
// Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

function onOpen() { // Add this only in case you want to call your function through a custom menu
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Add circles')
      .addItem('Add Blank Circles', 'addBlankCircles')
      .addToUi();
}

function addBlankCircles() {
  const rangeList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRangeList();
  rangeList.getRanges().forEach(range => {
    const columns = range.getNumColumns();
    const rows = range.getNumRows();
    const values = new Array(rows).fill("").map(() => new Array(columns).fill("◯"));
    range.setValues(values);
  })
}

function onSelectionChange(e) { // Change blank to black
  if (e.range.getValue() === "◯") e.range.setValue("⚫");
}
```